# C++ - struct member point to array

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

I have an array A[1000][3] and I want to pass it along with some others, as arguments for a thread function. The structure that will pass as an argument is the following:

```
 struct arg_struct{
// std::vector<Box> &box;
double A[1000][3];
};
```

In main I have a pointer to the struct and I try to assign the A array like this:

```
arg_struct *args=new arg_struct;
args->A=A;
```

but I get the error "invalid array assignment". Any ideas how to solve this?

Thank you for your time

UPDATE:How should I modify my code so the A in arg_struct points to the A array?

Comment: One does not simply... assign an array.

Answer (score 1):

Neither in C nor C++ can you assign naked arrays. Alas, in this case, `args->A` is not a pointer, it is *the array* itself. It degenerates to a pointer in many cases, but it's not a pointer!

Comment: If I copy the whole array to the args.A, I will have used memory for 2 arrays right? If so, can I just assign a pointer which will point to the A array?

Comment: Yes, although that sounds risky in a multithread environment.